# Fieldset tag is not working in my asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, html, fieldset, groupbox

i have a fieldset in my asp.net website to make a groupbox look alike.. but its not coming.
here's what i am doing :

```
<fieldset id="fl1" runat="server">
     <legend>My Group</legend>
</fieldset>
```

[image: screen shot of the page where its not working]

only `My Group` is coming the border isn't coming ... i also used `panel` but same issue...

i am using `ajax toolkit` and `update panel` in this page ...

what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fieldset is visible, it is just the border that isn't. Therefore you, presumably, have a style sheet that is removing the border.

Edit the style sheet so either it doesn't remove the border in the first place, or it adds one in explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything in the fieldset so it can't put a border around nothing.

```
<fieldset id="fl1" runat="server">
    <legend>My Group</legend>
    <!-- Put anything you want to be in the fieldset here. -->
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @ArindamDas, You need to provide your source code then. What you post isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net core pages do not seems to support all kind of fieldset elements.
It supports but now visible in browsers.

You may use, fieldset like this , As solid reference is supported.

```
    <fieldset style="border:0.5px solid">
```

=>>code goes here